# Connection refused error when try to connect HDFS in linux from Jupyter Notebook in Windows

Tags: python, apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark

I have installed Hadoop in the Vmware Ubuntu Machine and its working well in linux.

When i try to fetch data from jupyter notebook it throws connection refused error.

Below are the properties set in Hadoop files.

### core-site.xml:

```
<property>
<name>fs.default.name</name>
<value>hdfs://localhost:50000</value>
</property>
```

### hdfs-site.xml:

```
<property>
<name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
<value>/home/sankar/hadoop2-dir/namenode-dir</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
<value>/home/sankar/hadoop2-dir/datanode-dir</value>
</property>
```

### mapred-site.xml:

```
<property>
<name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
<value>yarn</value>
</property>
```

added JAVA_HOME entry in hadoop-env.sh , yarn-env.sh,mapred-env.sh

My machine Ip address is below,

[image: Machine Ip address]

open-ssh server also installed and set the keys in authorized_keys file.

## Error Message in Jupyter Notebook:

Read file from HDFS:

```
df_hdfs = spark.read.csv("hdfs://192.168.208.129:50000/input_data/realestate.csv")
```

[image: Error Message]

Please help me on this to resolve this connection refused error.

Comment: Your error says HDFS isn't running at `192.168.208.129`. Read the link in the message to diagnose ... However, since you have a core-site XML file, why do you need to use `hdfs://192.168.208.129:50000` instead of `spark.read.csv("/input_data)`??

Comment: @OneCricketeer Hi its because Hadoop is running in Linux machine (Vmware) and Jupyter notebook i edited in windows machine. So that i am using Linux machine Ip address to point hdfs.  But stuck with this connection refused error

Comment: You should use port forwarding from the VM to your host, not give a specific IP address. Still, the link in the error tells you all that you need to know

Comment: @OneCricketeer i am new to this.. Dont know how to do port forwarding from VM to host